# Sencha Touch: setting up autoload to include html file

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, autoload

I have set up a simple panel in Sencha Touch with 2 tabs:

```
ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    title: "home",
    iconCls: "home",
    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'Playlist',
        scroll: 'vertical',
        html: 'test'
    },{
        title: 'Comments',
        scroll: 'vertical',
        autoLoad: {url: 'disqus.html', scripts: true}
    }]
});

Ext.reg('homecard', ToolbarDemo.views.Homecard);
```

On the 'Comments' tab I am trying to include a disqus.html file which is at the same level as the index.html file for my app, but nothing is showing up.  From googling about it would seem that I have entered the autoload code correctly, but perhaps I have missed out another step?

Could someone help me on my way?

Thanks,

Nick

Disqus code:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = 'monthlymixup'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        // The following are highly recommended additional parameters. Remove the slashes in front to use.
        var disqus_identifier = 'test';
        // var disqus_url = 'http://example.com/permalink-to-page.html';

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Answer (score 3):

The "autoLoad" property is only in ext.js and not yet available in sencha-touch.

But you can do something like this (Your mileage WILL vary):

```
Ext.setup({
onReady: function() {
    var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        type: 'dark',
        sortable: true,
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: '1',
            cls: 'card1',
        }, {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            html: '2',
            cls: 'card2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Tab 3',
            html: '3',
            cls: 'card3'
        }]
    });
    Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'disqus.html',
      success: function(response, opts) {
      tabPanel.items.get(2).update(response.responseText, true);  //2nd parameter is "loadScripts"
    }
    });
  }
});
```

(disqus.html)

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>Hello World.</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried implementing your solution.  When I include disqus.html at the same level as index.html nothing shows up in Tab 3.  Prior to including it I just got the html '3' in Tab 3.  Should the disqus.html show up in Tab 3?

Comment: It does for me, are you running in a web server or opening via "file://" from the command line?

Comment: If I ran it from the command line, I did get 3, b/c I got an "origin" error.  I tested with Chrome, and the console provides a lot of info.

Comment: I am running from a webserver

Comment: What are the contents of your disqus.html field?  I've added my contents above.

Comment: I am now testing with your basic html in disqus.html and still am just seeing '3' on the third tab. Is there any other code I need anywhere in index.html, other than including sencha-touch.js, app.js and the CSS files?

Comment: Thanks, when I copied your code/structure I got it working with "Hello World" in disqus.html, but when I actually include the code I need for Disqus to work (which I have now included in my original post), nothing shows.

Comment: Nick, I didn't know what was in your disqus.html, I didn't know there was script code in there.  Scripts do not load by default (security).  I've updated my code in the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated my code to match yours, but nothing shows on Tab 3 where the Disqus comments should show.  I have updated the Disqus code in my original post above so that it includes details for Disqus for my domain.  Could you copy this into your disqus.html file and see if Disqus comments show up for you?  Thanks

Comment: I will give that a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Nick, I cannot get the loadScripts to actually load scripts, it doesn't seem to run them.  But, I think that what you're trying to accomplished may be able to be done another way.  There are lots of techniques that will do cross site requests.  You may want to look into JSONP or HTML5's cross domain scripting.  Or you could have a proxy on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to bring a piece of code that I use to get an external html. As you may note, you should use callback, instead of success function. Not sure why, often the result goes to failure function.

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        callback: function(options, success, response) {
            // do what you need with response.responseText
            // I'm updating a panel with styleHtmlContent: true,
        }
    });
```